# Implementing KS test for lognormal fit

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

So I have some stock price data and I want to test whether the prices follow the lognormal distribution. My code is as follows:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
print(stats.kstest(df['DJIA'], "lognorm", stats.lognorm.fit(df['DJIA'])))
```

The results are as follows:

```
KstestResult(statistic=0.90996368658950855, pvalue=0.0)
```

p-value of zero means that the data do not fit a lognormal distribution, which is not possible, as stock prices are expected to be lognormally distributed. The histogram of the prices is as follows:

[image]

I'm trying to fit the histogram with the lognormal function, but unable to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the pvalue of zero indicates a high degree of certainty that your distribution is lognormal. Google pvalue

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did some research and got the following:            H0:  the data are lognormally distributed;
Ha:  the data are not lognormally distributed;                                                                 Here as p=0.0 (<0.05), we reject H0 at the 5% level. Does this imply the data are not lognormally distributed? Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.Thank you.

Comment: I can't speak to the implementation of scipy's kstest as to which they positioned as the null hypothesis. Or if they are returning a 1 - p. I'd experiment with it with identical distributions and obviously different distributions to see the results. And also add a scipy tag to the question.

Comment: How big is your sample?  (I.e. what is `len(df['DJIA'])`)?

Comment: len(df['DJIA']) is 6,492

Comment: Well, that is the theory. In real life you can have all kinds of distributions. And the distribution you posted does not look like a log normal at all. That's aside, Kolmogorov-Smirnov is a very strict test in that it only looks at the largest deviation between the empirical and the theoretical distribution. So if you have an outlier, it will sure reject the null hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any other test out there which I can use to prove that the data does follow a lognormal distribution? I looked at the Anderson-Darling test, but it does not support lognormal functionality. Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to fit the price data when you should be fitting the price *distribution*. Try fitting the count data from a histogram. The plot you show doesn't look like a histogram of the stock prices, it looks like a bar graph of price data.

```
count, bins, ignored = plt.hist(df['DJIA'], 100, normed=True, align='mid')
params = stats.lognorm.fit(count)
stats.kstest(count, "lognorm", params)
```

Be careful with kstest and fit because log-normal is a continuous distribution, and your histogram is discrete.